# Laravel, many-to-many relationship among multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many, relation

I Have multiple models that have many to many relationship

Here are the models

- News Section
- Categories
- Sub Categories
- Approved News
- Pending News

Each **News Section** can have multiple **Categories**.

Each **Category** can have multiple **Sub Categories**.

Each **Sub Category** can has multiple **Approved News** and **Pending News**.

I want to have **News** with **Categories**, **Sub Categories** and **Pending / Approve news**

and stuff like

**Categories**  with **Sub Categories** and **Approve news**

I tried with pivot tables but not able to get results

Models are as follow

**News Section**

```
class NewsSection extends Model
{
     public function categories()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Category**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcats(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
    public function newssections(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(NewsSection::class);
    }
}
```

**SubCategory**

```
class SubCategory extends Model
{
    public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function approvednews(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(ApprovedNews::class);
    }

   public function pendingnews(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(PendingNews::class);
   }
```

}

**ApprovedNews**

```
class ApprovedNews extends Model
{

    public function subcategories (){
     return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class);
   }
}
```

**PendingdNews**

```
class PendingdNewsextends Model
{

    public function subcategories (){
     return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
}
```

**Update**
This what I have done so far

> $news =Category::with('subcats.approvednews')->where('id',1)->get();

I got all the approved news with subcategories and categories

how can i modify this to get specific subcats and approved news per category, if i do this

> $news =Category::with('subcats.approvednews')->where('subcats.id',1)->get();

I get an error like id ambiguous

Is it possible to pick and chose items from relation for instance return just **2 subcats** and **3 approved news** for each **subcat** of **selected category**

or

get count of **approved news** and **pending news** per **subcat** and **category**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual problem you encountered?

Comment: When i try to get approved news for any category i get all items return i m doing like this
$items=Category::with('subcategory')->where('id',1)->get();
and in inverse its not getting categories or main section

Comment: Can you update the question with a concrete code sample of what you are trying to do and what you get instead?

Comment: @Rao When you are doing `$items=Category::with('subcategory')->where('id',1)->get();` are you trying to get the category with the id of 1, or categories where the subcategory is 1?

Comment: please look at the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "error like id ambiguous" means that you need to specify the table in your `where('id', 1)` like `where('table.id', 1)` so that MySQL knows which `id` column in which table you mean.

You can [constrain the models returned by `with`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) like this:

```php
Category::with(['subcats' => function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', 1);
}]);
```

Also you can [count relations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$subcat = SubCategory::withCount(['approvednews']);
$subcat->approvednews_count;
```

Limiting eager loaded relations is not possible [per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

A workaround may be to go the other way round starting from `ApprovedNews`:

```php
ApprovedNews::whereHas(['subcategories' => function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', 1);
}])->limit(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions of how you can get this to work. In your comments, you say you are getting an issue doing the following:

`$items=Category::with('subcategory')->where('id',1)->get();`

Where is `'subcategory'` coming from? By the looks of your model, your relationship between Category and Subcategory is called `subcats`. So you would need to change it to:

`$items=Category::with('subcats')->where('id',1)->get();`

And if you dump that out, you should see that you will get the category where the ID is 1, and the subcategories loaded in. A way to test that your relationships are working would be something like this:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$subCats = $category->subcats()->get();
dd($subCats);
```

In your relationships, instead of using `SubCategory::class` I would suggest trying `return $this->belongsToMany('App\SubCategory');` so that the models are definitely connected.

Once you have tested that your relationships between one another work, you can get started on testing that you can go from a->b->c etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be using "Nested Eager Loading" and "scope", you can do something like

```
$pendings = NewSection::with('categories.subCategories')->pending()->get()
$approved = NewSection::with('categories.subCategories')->approved()->get()
```

not tested it, but you can try, may be with some modification, you can reach to your goal.

if you want return one collection, you may like to merge it

```
$approved->merge($pendings);
```

but, you should avoid it.